# Error when sending email via Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, email, laravel, gmail

When I try to send an e-mail through my website running Laravel 5, I get this exception:

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 l140sm14142372oig.11 -  gsmtp
```

Here is my env configuration

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=example
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Code works on local and other website but not work on my new website on new hosting. I allow access from less-secure apps. What can be problem?

Comment: It could be possible that Google/Gmail has blocked access to your new web hosting. Have you tried using using another script / library (like PHPMailer) to see if you can connect to gmail and send an email via your new web hosting account?

Comment: It's possible the security settings of your Gmail don't like the login from the 3rd party application. [Go to this link](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Ohgodwhy, that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that G-Mail doesn't like the 3rd party application that's connecting to it.

If you are sure the credentials are correct, then [visit this link to check if you need to approve the application](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)